# Get property of initially empty object after adding properties

Tags: javascript, angular, object, key, key-value

I am trying to make a data converting script (with Angular) and need to access properties of an object which is initially empty (see simplified code below). However, I get an error message that says that the key does not exist in the object. I can not add the keys when initialising the object because the data might be different in the next run. I have tried different methods of accessing the key but I have not yet figured it out. I hope someone can help me!

*TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '1' can't be used to index type '{}'.   Property '1' does not exist on type '{}'.*

> ```
>     data = {};
>     const key = 1;
>     for( let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
>       Object.assign(data, {[i]: 'test'});
>     }
>
>     if(key in data){
>       data[key] = 'test2';
>       data.key = 'test2';
>     }
> ```

Comment: const data: any = {}; is this resolving your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the property names at first, you can use `any`. Initialize it like this:

```
data: any = {};
```

If you know the property types (e.g. all the properties are strings), then you can type it something like this:

```
data: { [key: string]: string } = {};
```

Then it will work.